# How to find my php-fpm.sock?

Tags: php, linux, sockets, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm running Wordpress with: Nginx + PHP-FPM + APC + W3 Total Cache + PageSpeed.

After 3 days researching and configuring, I succeeded to make it work.
I configured PHP-FPM to run via 127.0.0.1:9000. But now I want to configure via Socket.

The problem is that I can't find the socket path in my server. I just found `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid`, but `php-fpm.sock` was not there.

Running `whereis php-fpm` the output is:

```
php-fpm: /usr/sbin/php-fpm /etc/php-fpm.d /etc/php-fpm.conf /usr/share/man/man8/php-fpm.8.gz
```

But there isn't any `php-fpm.sock` there.

How can I find `php-fpm.sock`?

My specs:

- Amazon Micro EC2
- Linux version 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64 Red Hat 4.6.3-2 (I think it's based on CentOS 5)
- PHP 5.3.26 (fpm-fcgi)

Comment: Just as an FYI, `Linux version 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64` or similar is [Amazon Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). It's based on CentOS, and is compatible with those packages, but is not quite the same thing.

Comment: `grep '^listen' /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Answer (score 78):

I know this is old questions but since I too have the same problem just now and found out the answer, thought I might share it. The problem was due to configuration at `pool.d/` directory.

Open

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

find

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

change to

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Restart both nginx and php5-fpm service afterwards and check if php5-fpm.sock already created.

Comment: Everything was telling me to change to 127.0.0.1:9000 this finally told me the right way and the file was created and everything worked :)

Comment: I don't have such folder `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`... I have PHP7 installed, not 5

Comment: found the answer somewhere else! You do **not** need to change the line `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` at all!!!! i have php7 and you simply should use `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` in your server config file

Comment: @vsync LOL, are you sure about this? I have been on the same misery for ages. Everyone is saying to change the `www.conf` but I can't find where the `..fpm.sock` file is located. are you sure?

Comment: @entegra - I don't remember anymore, my last comment is over a year old, sorry

Comment: For RHEL, CentOS, and other RPM distributions, try: `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: It works on php 7.4 for me, i think it should work for every other versions `listen = /var/run/php{version}-fpm.sock`

Comment: After the change, i discovered the need of multiple listeners, this [configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04) helped me.

Answer (score 23):

I faced this same issue on CentOS 7 years later

Posting hoping that it may help others...

**Steps:**

*FIRST*, configure the php-fpm settings:

-> `systemctl stop php-fpm.service`

-> `cd /etc/php-fpm.d`

-> `ls -hal` (should see a www.conf file)

-> `cp www.conf www.conf.backup` (back file up just in case)

-> `vi www.conf`

-> `:/listen =` (to get to the line we need to change)

-> `i` (to enter VI's text insertion mode)

-> change from `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` TO `listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`

-> `Esc` then `:/listen.owner` (to find it) then `i` (to change)

-> UNCOMMENT the `listen.owner = nobody` AND `listen.group = nobody` lines

-> Hit `Esc` then type `:/user =` then `i`

-> change `user = apache` TO `user = nginx`

-> AND change `group = apache` TO `group = nginx`

-> Hit `Esc` then `:wq` (to save and quit)

-> `systemctl start php-fpm.service`  (now you will have a php-fpm.sock file)

*SECOND*, you configure your `server {}` block in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.  Then run:`systemctl restart nginx.service`

*FINALLY*, create a new .php file in your /usr/share/nginx/html directory for your Nginx server to serve up via the internet browser as a test.

-> `vi /usr/share/nginx/html/mytest.php`

-> type `o`

-> `<?php echo date("Y/m/d-l"); ?>` (PHP page will print date and day in browser)

-> Hit `Esc`

-> type `:wq`  (to save and quite VI editor)

-> open up a browser and go to: `http://yourDomainOrIPAddress/mytest.php`
(you should see the date and day printed)

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me. However I also had to change the `listen.owner` and `listen.group` from `nobody` to `nginx` otherwise this will result (13 permission denied)

Answer (score 13):

Check the config file, the config path is `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, there you'll find the path by config and if you want you can change it.

**EDIT**:
well you're correct, you need to replace `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` to `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.sock`, then you need to run `sudo service php5-fpm restart`, and make sure it says that it restarted correctly, if not then make sure that `/var/run/` has a folder called `php5-fpm`, or make it listen to `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` cause i don't think the folder inside `/var/run` is created automatically, i remember i had to edit the start up script to create that folder, otherwise even if you `mkdir /var/run/php5-fpm` after restart that folder will disappear and the service starting will fail.

Comment: In my "www.conf" was configured "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000". There aren't any sockt path... If I config "/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock" in that file, and put this patsh in "nginx.conf" I get "Bad Gatway" (I think it's because the "/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock" is not there)

Comment: The folder `/var/run/php-fpm/` was already created. But the only file inside that folder was `php-fpm.pid`. I created an empty file called `php-fpm.sock` configure nginx and php-fpm, but without success. I think the problem is that I don't have the `.sock` file. But how can I get it?

Comment: ok let me make something clear, the sock file isn't some file that you create, when the service is started successfully it creates the file, did you try to start the service like i said? try running `sudo service php5-fpm status` it probably would say that it isn't running, did you check the error log to see why it isn't starting ?

Comment: Yeah... the service is up. I can see Nginx connecting with PHP-FPM using 'top'. But the problem is that even starting the service it didn't created the '.sock'. I'm using Amazon Micro (CentOS 5), don't know if something is different there

Comment: Instead of listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.sock this listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock solved the problem for me.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem. Could someone clarify what series of paths need to exist where?

Comment: what exactly is your "problem", what is your setup, what is your distro, instead of downvoting a working answer for someone else try asking your own question with your own config

Comment: you just saved me a shit load of trouble, thanks.  i had to create the `php-fpm` dir inside `/srv/http/run` in my case

Answer (score 8):

Solved in my case, i look at

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and error is php5-fpm.sock not found

I look at `sudo ls -lah /var/run/`

there was no php5-fpm.sock

I edit the www.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

change

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

for

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

and reboot

Answer (score 0):

When you look up your `php-fpm.conf`

```
example location:
cat /usr/src/php/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf
```

you will see, that you need to configure the PHP FastCGI Process Manager to actually use Unix sockets. Per default, the `listen` directive` is set up to listen on a TCP socket on one port. If there's no Unix socket defined, you won't find a Unix socket file.

```
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all IPv4 addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '[::]:port'            - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue when I first run LEMP on centos7 refer to this **[post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7#step-four-%E2%80%94-configure-nginx-to-process-php-pages)**.

I restart nginx to test the phpinfo page, but get this

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/info.php is not unreachable now.

Then I use `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` to see more info. I find is the 
php-fpm.sock file not exist. Then I reboot the system, everything is OK.

Here may not need to reboot the system as Fath's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419567/6521116), just reload nginx and php-fpm.

[restart php-fpm](https://serverfault.com/q/189940/368057)

[reload nginx config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292533/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP by running the command

```
sudo apt install php
```

Next, install php-fpm

```
sudo apt install php-fpm
```

php-fpm will be installed automatically. Check the location of the sock file by running the command

```
find / -name "*fpm.sock"
```