# Reload Nginx configuration

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver

I am trying to modify the Nginx config file to remove a "rewrite".

Currently, I have this config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name amc.local;
        return 301 https://$host:8443/index.html;
    }
}
```

Now I want to reload this config file, I tried

```
nginx -s reload
nginx -c <conf file>
nginx -s stop/start
```

In the log file, there is the line

```
2014/01/22 11:25:25 [notice] 1310#0: signal process started
```

but the modifications are not loaded.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Maybe you're not doing it as root?

Try `sudo nginx -s reload`, if it still doesn't work, you might want to try `sudo pkill -HUP nginx`.

Comment: Even on Bitnami LAMP Stack, this method is working!
Thank you

Comment: @GangsarSwaPurba, glad it works!  It should work pretty much on any UNIX system, since it does not depend on any proprietary frameworks or system-specific scripts!

Answer (score 56):

If your system has `systemctl`

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

If your system supports `service` (using debian/ubuntu) try this

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

If not (using centos/fedora/etc) you can try the init script

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Comment: An equivalent without service is `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`. Would work on centos and debian as far as i know.

Comment: debian distros prefer the `service` keyword, some packages even give a warning if you use the `init.d` script, so I usually use the `service` and fall back to `init.d` if it doesn't work, either ways I'll add this tip to my answer

Comment: Thats interesting. I've never seen a warning. I always thought service ran the scripts in /etc/init.d/. I prefer service because its easier to type. Whats the technical reason for there being a warning thrown?

Comment: Thank you. That makes allot of sense. Also i found this [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/service.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/service.htm) i think its just the man pages, but it does explain how service create a minimal environment to run the scrips in. I guess it can help them run consistently between different distros.

Comment: It would work when you have a service for Nginx. The question is about the Nginx execution file not a service one...