# Reload nginx config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, nginx

How do I reload the nginx config file after editing it?
I'm using this with Rails on a Mac... but I'm brand new to nginx so I really don't know how to do this.
I've researched and tried `nginx -s reload` but that's just returning an error that there's no such file/directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload nginx configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292533/reload-nginx-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You can either restart nginx completely by something like `systemctl restart nginx` or `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx restart` or you can send a `signal` to its process to make it reload its configuration: `killall -s SIGHUP nginx`

Comment: I've tried all three of those suggestions, the terminal returned:
"No matching processes belonging to you were found"... "No such file or directory"... and "systemctl: command not found". Could it be a problem with the app?

Comment: No. From the tags you have used I see, that you are using OSX. I don't know how to restart services on OSX, but as it is more or less posix compatible chances are, that the signal solution works best. That said: If you don't have a killall-command try finding nginx PID with <code>ps</code> and send the signal using kill: "kill -s SIGHUP 1234"

Comment: isn't the whole point of `-s reload` to avoid downtime between the transition? using `restart` or `killall` kind of defeats that purpose

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that killall can only be used to kill processes. Instead it can send signals, one of which is `SIGUSR1`, another is `SIGHUP`. None of these kill the process, but they can be handled by the running process and "do things". In case of `SIGHUP` it is reload, see here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html and `SIGUSR1` is useful as well if you are using an external logrotate mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

I do it like this

```
killall -9 nginx; sleep 1; nginx
```

Comment: then you have at least a whole second of pure downtime, congratulations. Depending on what you're working on, that could cause a lot of problems.