# Simple nginx redirect doesn't match

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I was originally trying to do a complicated URL rewrite which I couldn't get working, so stripped it back to a simple URL redirect which should definitely work, instead it throws a 404.

Requests for [any_scheme]://www.mydomain.com/google should redirect to https://www.google.com/

nginx.conf
(not posted as it contains no server blocks so can't conflict?)

mydomain.com.conf:

```
server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;

    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location = /google {
        return 302 https://www.google.com/;
    }

    #rogue .htaccess files caught here
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

#force non-www. to www.
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Tried `nginx -t && service nginx reload` ?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Yep, with every change. Something must be conflicting elsewhere as this config is as clean as they come I think

Comment: Is there an access log entry corresponding to this 404 response?

Comment: x.x.x.x - - [06/Mar/2019:01:45:39 +0000] "GET /google/ HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; Swift 2 X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.76 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Comment: I wonder if any other location from `www.mydomain.com` works? Did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `curl -v` to debug what's going on with your server.
- Do you use `sites-available` / `sites-enabled`?  Don't.  See https://serverfault.com/a/870709/110020. The `sites-available` / `sites-enabled` is non-standard and is evil, don't use it, use `conf.d` instead.
- Make sure you actually reload nginx.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297545/1122270.  Try `sudo nginx -s reload` and `sudo pkill -HUP nginx` directly.
- Check both `error_log` as well as `access_log`.  Make sure the dates of events match the new requests that you're making.  I'd recommend opening several terminal windows, and doing a [`tail -f`](http://mdoc.su/o/tail.1) in each, then doing a few <kbd>return</kbd> presses to separate new input from the old one, only then doing the requests.
- Are you using any extra proxies on top of nginx?  Those might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I *think* `sudo nginx -s reload` did the trick. I have been using `systemctl reload nginx` which I believe is basically the same thing, so not sure *why*  it worked this time but it did. I will also take your advice on `sites-enabled`. For the record I'm using a Digital Ocean image of Ubuntu 16.04 LEMP. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log entry: you are requesting `/google/` (note the trailing slash), but this will not match up with `/google` location because there is no trailing slash there.

So you need two exact match locations:

```
location = /google {
    return 302 https://www.google.com/;
}

location = /google/ {
    return 302 https://www.google.com/;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my log file line was incorrect, I had been testing with and without slash and posted the wrong line. Even with the slash in the rule and testing slash in URL I get same response. Is there another way I can trace the problem?