# FuelPHP with Nginx routing not working

Tags: php, nginx, fuelphp

I'm new to FuelPHP and web development in general. I'm trying to redirect a user to a different controller but for some reason I can't get the page to display. The homepage displays fine and if I change the default homepage to the Blog page it displays fine.

Here is the link on the homepage:
    `<?php echo Html::anchor('blog', 'BLOG'); ?>`

Then I have the controller it points too:

```
class Controller_Blog extends Controller_Template {
public function action_index() {
return Response::forge(View::forge('blog/index', $views,false)->render());
}
```

When I click the link it takes me to 'mywebsite.com/blog' but it says "Access denied."

Here is my nginx virtual host:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mywebsite.com
index index.php index.html index.html

root /home/me/fuelphp_project/public;

location / {
index index.php
try_files $uri $uri @php_index;

location ~ \.php$ {
 deny all;
}

location @php_index {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param FUEL_ENV "production";
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

I'm not sure if I haven't setup FuelPHP correctly or it's Nginx. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you have deny all to your php files.

Comment: Removing that didn't change anything

Comment: check permissions and modify something like this : https://github.com/rajibmp/FuelPHP-Nginx/blob/master/nginx/sites-available/FuelPHP

Comment: No luck, that just gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error. Tried to fix that too but couldn't manage

Comment: 502 gives me that error if I use wrong fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;, can you use your unix socket?

Comment: No I changed it to `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` which gives no errors when running `nginx restart` and everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working. I will post the answer in case anyone else comes along this problem.
For clarification this is on an Ubuntu 16.04 server running Nginx 1.10.0 and php7.0-fpm trying to setup for a Fuelphp project.

Using this page from [ytsejam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388866/ytsejamas) as a guide https://github.com/rajibmp/FuelPHP-Nginx/blob/master/nginx/sites-available/FuelPHP

I changed a few things to suit my situation:

- Set the server_name to my server
- Set the root folder to the public folder of my fuelphp project
- I got rid of `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $script` and `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info` as they gave me errors complaining about undeclared variables.
- the access and error log files are in `/var/www/fuelphp/nginxlogs` for me
- set `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`
- `listen 80` not sure why it says to set it to port 57

Then I followed the tips given here about further setup for php7.0-fpm: [How to find my php-fpm.sock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570658/how-to-find-my-php-fpm-sock)

I think that was everything. Thank you for your help [ytsejam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388866/ytsejamas)!