# php-fpm.sock is missing: php7.2 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos, centos7

***Summary:I'm trying to use Nginx on PHP7.2 and CentOS 7, but can't find php-fpm.sock***

I used to use ***PHP7.0 on Ubuntu 16***. Recently, I switched to ***CentOS 7***. and now I'm trying to set it up with Nginx and the latest PHP (i.e. ***PHP7.2***)

On PHP7.0 on Ubuntu 16, the php-fpm's socket file was stored in...

`/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

However, on PHP7.2. and CentOS7, I don't see `/run/php/` directory. So, it's clear that Nginx on PHP7.2 and CentOS can't be configured in the say way

I searched Stackoverflow, but most of the posts were dealing with older versions of php (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570658/how-to-find-my-php-fpm-sock))

If I run `yum install php-fpm`, it results in `"already installed"`, so I'm sure php-fpm itself is already there

[image]

If I run "ps aux | grep php-fpm"...

[image]

I can see that there is a directly, named `/etc/php-fpm.d`, but it has only a file called `www.conf`, not a socket file.

[This tutorail](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) shows that the sock is stored as `/run/php-fpm/www.sock` on PHP7.2 and CentOS 7, but in my machine, there is only `php-fpm.pid`.

So, where did the sock file go? Any advice will be appreciated.

PS:I'm also interested in why Ubuntu+PHP7 and CentOS+PHP7.2 have such a difference regarding where to store PHP files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two distros (Ubuntu and CentOS) are using different package mechanisms (`apt` vs `yum`), different packages and different maintainers with different approach to things. So you may expect quite some difference in how things are structured or even work between the two systems.

The default PHP-FPM config by Remi, indeed has one pool listening on port 9000 (AFAIK).

If you want it to listen on a Unix socket, you have to adjust the PHP-FPM pool config. That is `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. So you'll want to specify there:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

This is just to give you an idea :)

Comment: FYI: when CentOS 7 was release, apache HTTP server version doesn't have UDS support, the reason why we choose to use a network socket for better compatibility. Switch to UDS is now possible as supported by both httpd and nginx.
See: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/ (§ 1.4.2)

Comment: More info: On Fedora and on upcoming EL-8 (8-beta is released), FPM use UDS, and both httpd and nginx use it, with the proper configuration provided (work out-of-the-box, without any change)